# how retrieve file from server from filelist (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have following script showing a nice listing of the content of a directory on the server. But how do I make this script open the file, as if it where in a html anchor tag, instead of show its name (with alert), when clicking on a filename?

[image]

The source of the code is at http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fileTreeDemo_1').fileTree({ root: '../../filetree/', script: 'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) { 
        alert(file);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="example">
    <h2>Default options</h2>
    <div id="fileTreeDemo_1" class="demo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to open a new page through Javascript.

One of 'em is:

```
window.location = 'url here';
```

Problem with that, however, is that the current tab/window will redirect to that file. Making the user leave the current page! To open the file in a *new window*, you can use:

```
 window.open('url here')
```

But this one also comes with its own caveats: browsers will warn the user of a pop-up being opened. And the user will have to manually grant the site permission to continue.

Mind you, in both situations a valid formatted url is required to work. Which means it requires the full http://www. what have you.

Comment: Something like <a href="">Download</a> would do for me with the file-reference filled in by the anonymous function passed with the fileTree call. How would I set that up with JavaScript (Ajax)?

Comment: I'm goind to have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp to see if that does the trick for me. I'll be back...